# Rendering a component adhoc without going through the state in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking for a way to replace a blocking [prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) call in an old system. It asks for the user's input in a blocking way:

```
 const name = prompt('name:', previousValue);

 if (name) {...
```

I would like to replace it with a React Component. I am using redux and context for i18n around the system so I was trying to find an elegant way to go about it. I want to be able to call it from every method in the application.

For now I rendered a Prompt component in the root App component and am exposing it through the context while passing a callback:

```
class App extends Component {

    getChildContext = () => {
        return {
            i18n: i18n,
            prompt: this.prompt
        }
    };

    state = {
        showPrompt: null,
    };

    prompt = (title, value, callback) => {
        this._prompt = {title, value, callback};

        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({showPrompt: true});
        }, 100);
    }

 // ...class continues...
```

usage:

```
this.context.prompt('name', '', callback: (occurrences) => {
        if (name) {
            this.props.changeName(name);
        }
    }
});
```

But surely someone has come with a better why?

Comment: are you using node in the backend?

Comment: For now Firebase but we are using Node for analytics

Comment: ok, you can use this package for prompts and alerts https://www.npmjs.com/package/vex-js